# DC excitation for generator

Tags: dc, generator

So i am spinning this generator to make variable frequency 3 phase AC. The exciter supply blew up this morning. The supply was a rectified single phase AC at 12vDC 40A DC. I am confused as to what the actual DC excitation volts needs to be?

Stator volts 230/460 amps 62/31
Rotor volts 210, Rotor amps 57

[image]

Comment: You have a 3-phase wound rotor induction motor with three windings and you attempt to connect a 2-wire DC supply to the rotor to make a 3-phase generator.  Google "3-phase wound rotor induction motor".  I'd stop before you do some actual damage.

Answer (score 2):

The nameplate is clearly marked "Wound Rotor Motor." The machine is certainly not a synchronous generator if any kind. It can be operated similarly to a normal three-phase induction motor by shorting the slip rings together. With the rings shorted, it will operate at 1165 RPM and produce 25 Hp to drive a load at a fixed speed. If a balanced, 3-phase resistive load is connected to the slip rings, the speed can be reduced by varying the resistance. The amount of speed reduction will be highly dependent on the load.

The motor can be operated as a doubly-fed induction generator with a controlled AC supply connected to the rotor. That is a rather complex machine. I can not begin to describe how it would need to be controlled and operated.